# Maven multi-module - build only a sub-module

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a multi-module project P with sub-modules A, B and C.

A is dependent on B.
B is dependent on C.

With B and C neither available in remote or local repos, is it possible to build from A's directory passing the relative path to dependent modules B and C.

Comment: Why don't you build from P?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you mean but you should be able achieve what you want by doing this:

```
directory-of-P $ mvn clean install -pl :<artifactId-of-A> -am
```

or if on Windows:

```
C:\Directory\Of\P>mvn clean install -pl :<artifactId-of-A> -am
```

There is no need to change the directory to `A`. In fact, Maven works best if you always work from the directory containing your root POM. Then you don't need to figure out how many levels deep a certain module is located, Maven will find it for you if it is part of the reactor.